# Rheem KW-18 tripping breaker

Tags: water, heater, tankless

I installed a Rheem KW-18 tankless water heater in the house 3-4 years ago. I have never had an issue other than the lights will blink when the water heater is running. We adjusted to that and it's no big deal.
Now the water heater is tripping one of the 40 amp breakers by the time you finish a shower.
Nothing else on the house is calling for hot water.
Any feedback would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Pete in NE Ct.

Comment: Is it a plain breaker or is it a GFCI or AFCI ("TEST" button or indicator lights)?

Comment: There are (2) regular 40amp double pole breakers (220 amps) Only one of them trips.

Comment: 220 amps? Probably 220 volts. Which is really 240 volts in most places now. But OK "regular not GFCI or AFCI". So either a breaker is wearing out or something wrong with the water heater, because normal usage should not trip the breakers.

Comment: Did you do a load calculation on the panel when you installed it?  Lights blinking might mean it is taking too much power from your panel.

Comment: Yes, 220 volts, sorry. It has worked without issue for 3-4 years. I would expect longer life from a Rheem. There was no load test done for installation.

Comment: Just reset it and got an error message E-5. First time I have seen that.

Comment: The Rheem manual should have the error codes in it.  It would be nice if E-5 meant the same for everything, but it might be different even with different models of the same maker.  Can google load calculation and do one yourself, but it should have been done if professionally installed(hopefully).